# What's the formula for getting the time of the most change

Tags: calculus

If say for 100 seconds the temperature swings between 20C to 70C but I want to know what 5 second span has the highest change in temperature, how will I know the second or time that it took place?

Comment: It depends on what model the temperature change uses.  Is it linear?  Exponential?

Comment: Make a list of the temperature at each time in $5$ second increments.  Subtract the previous one from each, take the absolute value, and pick the highest.  If you tabulate the temperatures in a spreadsheet it is easy.

Comment: @Ross I came up with the same idea.

Comment: It depends on how you are given the temperature.  If it is in a formula, you can try to do something analytic.  If it is just a list, this is the best you can do.